# Destroy And Object , Client Side

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I can't delete an object on the client side, using the destroy function, I created an admin role and gave it all the necessary rights, but unfortunately I am always sent object not found when I want to delete an object. Voila Mon code.
`

```
    user = getCurrentParseUser();
    sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
    query = new Parse.Query(BillingPackage);
    billingPackage = await query.get(billingPackageId);

    console.log("billingPackage",billingPackage); //the object is retrieve here

    if(billingPackage){
      await billingPackage.destroy({sessionToken:sessionToken});
      return {status: true, message: "The Billing Package Has Been Deleted"}
    }else{
      return {status: false, message: "The Billing Package Already Deleted"}
    }`
```

The CLP Where Set True For All the action (create, read, delete, find)

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the session token to the query to find it.

`billingPackage = await query.get(billingPackageId, {sessionToken:sessionTokne});`

Comment: Next time be sure to use a debugger to step through, you would have seen what line was throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in as the current user (`user = getCurrentParseUser()`), then you don't need to pass the sessionToken to the destroy method. If you are not logged in as the currentUser, you will not be allowed to get the other users sessionToken.

Assuming that you are logged in as the current user or you are a user who can delete the object, I have corrected your code bellow. Hope to be used as a reference for others too.

```js
try {
  const billingPackage = await new Parse.Query(BillingPackage).get(billingPackageId);
  if (billingPackage) {
    try {
      await billingPackage.destroy();
      return {
        status: true,
        message: "The Billing Package Has Been Deleted"
      }
    } catch (parseError) {
      return {
        {
          status: false,
          message: parseError.message
        }
      }
    }
  }
} catch (parseError) {
  console.log(parseError.message);
}
```